# why I am getting an error message data type mismatch in criteria expression, error 2950?

Tags: ms-access

this is my code:

```
If Isnull([RECRUITMENT_NR]) Then
    Beep
End if

If Not Isnull([RECRUITMENT_NR]) Then

open form
formname frmHR_RECRUITMENT
view Form
where condition =="[RECRUITMENT_NR]=&[RECRUITMENT_NR]

Data mode
Window mode Dialog
```

please note we run in access 2010

Error message: 
    Data type mismatch in criteria expression
    error# 2950

any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are those lines following `"If Not Isnull([RECRUITMENT_NR]) Then"`?  It doesn't look like VBA code.

Comment: @HansUp I think it's VBA, a little mangled. I recognised the DoCmd.OpenForm method and some keyword arguments. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can clear up the code somewhat:

```
If IsNull([RECRUITMENT_NR]) Then
  Beep
  Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm _
  "frmHR_RECRUITMENT" _
, acNormal, _ ' open in normal view
, "[RECRUITMENT_NR] = " & [RECRUITMENT_NR] _ ' explanation below
, acFormEdit _ ' allow user to add and edit records
, acDialog
```

The only thing I am leery of is the `[RECRUITMENT_NR]` field that you're checking in the VBA before setting the form filter condition. I'm assuming this code is running as part of some form's VBA code and the form has a field named `[RECRUITMENT_NR]`, and the `frmHR_RECRUITMENT` form you're then opening has an underlying data field *also* named `[RECRUITMENT_NR]`. That should work ... but to be honest I'm not sure. I will probably re-adjust my answer depending on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary variable of your control value, and pass that to the where condition of the form open.

Here's what your macro should look like:

```
SetTempVar
Name tmpRecruitment_NR
Expression = [RECRUITMENT_NR]

If IsNull([RECRUITMENT_NR]) Then
    Beep
    StopMacro
Else
    OpenForm
        Form Name frmHR_RECRUITMENT
        View Form
        Filter Name
        Where Condition = [RECRUITMENT_NR]=[TempVars]![tmpRecruitment_NR]
        Data Mode
        Window Mode Dialog
End If
RemoveAllTempVars
```